# Why are constants called "constant variable" in Google Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, constants, chromium

I've noticed that when you try to change a const value the Chrome Console console returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

Are there any special reasons for calling a constant a "constant variable"? It seems paradoxical to me.

Comment: Firefox says `invalid assignment to const 'a'`

Comment: What are you running to get that error?

Comment: @ChrisG I edited the question, i'm using MS Edge. Haven't tested in other browsers.

Comment: @Dom
`const a = 0;
a = 20;`

Comment: @ViniciusGallotti thank you! Notice what the error message says after running `const a = 0; a = 20;` (adding a semicolon at the end of that statement). You're running this in console, yes? What error do you get when you use `var` instead of `const`?

Comment: @Dom Thans for your reply!. If i use var i does not return an error. My question is about the terminology used, not the error itself.

Comment: The phrase 'constant variable' sure is delightfully ironic...

Comment: @ViniciusGallotti Wait, are you using Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because "variable" is a general term for a name that holds a value, common to most programming languages.

Also, the term "constant" by itself can be confusing, because it's often used to refer to primitive, literal values like `1` and `"foo"`.

So a "constant variable" is a variable that has been declared with a `const` statement. Yes, it's an oxymoron because the value can't vary. But it acts the same as variables in all other respects. There's no other common term for the thing that writable variables and constant variables have in common.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my initial question since I thought it was a bit misleading. "truly constant" meaning a mutable variable. Many transpilers treat const as though it's mutable which is simply wrong in my opinion.

Comment: I don't see a change to the question that invalidates my answer. Transpilers can't make the JavaScript interpreter block assignments to a variable.

Comment: I misinterpreted the answer that was asked. Your answer definitely explains the why. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As a beginner programmer I was expecting something like this, coming from practical usage in older programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the term [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)) implies mutability. It may hold *varying* values (e.g. during different runs of the program), but not necessarily be assignable. Notice that a [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(mathematics)) in mathematics never changes its value either.

Comment: The term `variable` literally means "something that can/will change"

Comment: @ChrisG I disagree. A variable *may* be changed, but that doesn't mean it can or should.

Comment: @ChrisG Would you say the `i` in `for (const i of arr)` "changes"? Yes, it does, but each `i` is still constant and cannot be assigned to.

Comment: No, obviously not, since it's a const. But let and var both can and do change. And in mathematics, a simple linear equation like `y = x²` is not about fixed values in any sense, yet x and y are variables, are they not?

Comment: @marco-a Sorry, that may be semantically true, but practically speaking, in the context of JS, that's nonsense. You specifically use `const` to declare an entity that won't change, and use `let` or `var` otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisG But still still `i` holds *varying* values during the loop - that's where the name comes from, `i` is a variable. Just like in maths, where you say "for all `y` that have the value `x²`, some proposition holds…". Even if you have a formula with a free variable, as soon as you bind it, all instances will have the same constant values - e.g. in `y+y` you'll never have one `y=2` and the other `y=3`.

Comment: But a single `i` doesn't change, it's redeclared as a fresh `const` in each iteration of the loop. This is clearly an edge case, not how `const` is used in every other case.

Comment: The adjective "variable" literally means "able to vary".

Comment: @ChrisG Well, "practically" speaking, almost *nothing* in your computer's memory is "constant", so why bother with the term "constant" when everything's a variable?

Comment: @marco-a You can move the goalposts wherever you like, I'll stick to JS code.

Comment: @ChrisG No, we do talk about computers after all, aren't we?

Comment: @ChrisG What I wanted to get across is, that "constant" *is* about semantics.

Comment: @ChrisG No. The edge case is the `const` that is always assigned the same value, like `const PI = 3.14…`. The general case is `function(x) { const y = x*x; }` where `y` varies from call to call, just like `x`, and that's why they're called *variables* in computer science lingo.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree with all of that. I just completely disagree with your answer. The term itself implies mutability (vary-able), and a variable in mathematics is not something that has a fixed value unless we're talking about a very small and specific subset of mathematics ("solve for x"). And `y+y` is `2y`, so obviously not `2*2` and `2*3` at the same time, but again `2y = x` is not about fixed values at all, just about a relation between to arbitrary quantities.

Comment: Also, yes, like Barmar said, computer lingo calls a word that has a value a variable in general, and a const is part of that group but just happens to be immutable. But you could just say "in programming you use variables and constants", as opposed to "variables and constant variables".

Comment: @ChrisG A variable in mathematics has a *fixed definition*. It might be bound to arbitrary values, but it has no state, it cannot be reassigned. That's what mutability means.

Comment: I don't think there's any point in arguing about this further. You keep saying things that I agree with (a variable has a fixed definition) but that are completely besides the point (since that doesn't mean it has a fixed *value*). The wikipedia article you linked to starts with `In mathematics, a variable is a symbol which functions as a placeholder for varying expression or quantities`. And then there's [Euler's variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant